# How to change data email of invoice during place new order?

Tags: magento-1.7, email-templates

I have to change label from email of invoice. But I am not getting how to do it? Can you please suggest me way.

I have attach image. And mark as yellow color, which I want to change label.

[image]

As I research, I have find this string "**{{var order.shipping_description}}**" in invoice_new.html as an email template. Anyone tell me how can I change "**{{var order.shipping_description}}**" value in invoice_new.html.
Please help me asap.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That information is in the field `shipping_description` of the order object.

```
$order->setData('shipping_description', 'Some description')
```

should do what you want.

Comment: In which location. I mean in which file I have to modify for this? Can you please explain me in detail?

Comment: Try the event `sales_order_save_before`

Comment: Sorry, I am not getting your point.

Comment: http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-event-observer-with-save-before-and-save-after/